# Make a div containing img take full height

Tags: html, css, html5boilerplate

This question have been asked a lot on the web. But each try don't suceed

For a Website I need to make a header, I'm using django + boilerplate (I think that's boilerplate should be the cause, as copy paste of my code in js fiddle works, while it doesn't on local).

Here is the HTML I use:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="networking">
        <div id="title">
            EasyMusik
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="{% static "img/icons/myzik.svg" %}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#topbar{
    display:block;
    background-color : #29A329;
    position: relative;
    float: top;
}
#tobbar div{
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#networking{
    padding-left:25%;
}
#networking div{
    display:inline-block;
}
#title{
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#logo img{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#logo{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left:15px;
    background-color : #FF0000;
}
```

And I got this [result](http://puu.sh/bbyCj/6671f14ca0.png)

I want the Red area to fullfill the green one. Wich property should i add/remove to achieve that?

EDIT: Finally managed to get a fiddle: 
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vfxa0xef/1/)

Comment: Fullfill as in.. transparent?

Comment: The entire thing is an image, you can't just erase the red background of the music note with CSS--if that's what you're after.

Comment: @davidxd33 I don't want to erase that background, And if you take a look at my Css, you should see I placed this background. I want this background to begin at the top of the green bar, and end at the green bar bottom.

Comment: you need to set a width to the image

Comment: Set the image to height = 100%? Do you have a fiddle here to check it out?

Comment: @davidxd33 that's the point, But the html is updated, As I saidI'm using html5 boilerplate with this, and this is (I think), the cause of my problem, as if I copy this in jsfiddle, it works.

Comment: But the link provided isn't an example, please set up a fiddle so I can try to help. It's only an image and I can't work with it.

Comment: @davidxd33 Please take time to read : It works if I set up a fiddle with the same code! But in the localhost, it doesn't.

Comment: So check out with firebug and try to disable some classes - it works with the same setup in fiddle?

Comment: Then you have some overrides happening on your localhost. Most likely because of external CSS files you're including, just use firebug or inspector to check out what's going on here--since you claim it works on jsfiddle.

Comment: Well it making me mad, I made a retry now on jsfiddle and it does work. Anyway, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfxa0xef/1/) will help

Comment: @derdida Finally I think I was wrong, Removing every boilerplate related stuff doesn't remove the issue...

Comment: @CarlierRobin: Do you want something like this? [View](http://prntscr.com/4hdnfm)

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Exactly! if it's possible to make the title after obviously but I don't think it will cause problem

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi No problem, post it, I'll adapt my own Css with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the worked for me. Though its not your CSS.

**CSS:**

```
.parent
{
width:100%;
background-color:Green;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
font-size:24px;
}
.sub
{
width:50px;
background-color:Red;
height:50px;
display: inline-block;
}
.img
{
vertical-align:middle;
padding-top:15px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
Easy Muzik
<div class="sub">
<img alt="" class="img" src="style/img.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give #topbar a height. If you want your child container to be 100% height or width, your parent container has to have a height or width specified. Good luck!

```
    #topbar{
        display:block;
        background-color : #29A329;
        position: relative;
        float: top;
        height: 200px
    }
```